# Spotfire insert Median line in line chart

Tags: spotfire

I have multiple lines in a Spotfire line chart visualization. How can I add a Median Line of those lines. I wish to avoid adding a Calculated Column. I've tried Lines & Curves but I may have overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

Lines and curves would be where you'd do it at.

```
Right Click > Properties > Lines & Curves > Add > Horizontal Line > Straight Line...
```

Then, just change the aggregated value to `Median` for the column you are aggregating.

Also, after you click ok, scroll down and there is an option for **One per:** which you can make one line for all of the data, or a median for each line, or for each trellis panel

Comment: Thanks, but this just added a horizontal line. I am looking for a Median Line that appears as a curve, not flat.

Comment: Well that's not a line, it's a curve. What would the different point on this curve come from? The median of what?